# How to load style.scss file in application.css file ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have ruby on rails project in which I want to include scss files in my style sheets that is application.css

The directory structure is look like below:

[image]

The problem is that when I try to do this in my application.css file:

```
 *= require font-awesome
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require slick
 *= require basic-theme
 *= require style
 *= require_self


@import url("style.scss"); //it is in scss folder.
```

it still does not parse the code in it. Also if I set the path with assets/ it does load it but gives error like:

```
Sass::SyntaxError in Home#index

Undefined variable: "$base-font".
```

How I can easily import all these scss files in my rails app? Also any best practices please?

Answer (score 0):

Instead you need to use

```
@import "<relative path to style.css without .scss>"
```

Comment: `style.scss` contains code like `@import 'base/variables';
@import 'base/mixins';
@import 'base/base';` how it will work in this case? Also another file with name style is already imported and working fine that contains non scss code.